# SQL-manipulating strings

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'll try and make this clear...
Let's say I have a table with 2 columns. issue_number and issue_text. I need to grab 2 strings out of the issue_text column. The first string is something that can be hard coded with case statements since there are only so many types of issues that can be logged (note, i know this isn't the best way)

```
case
 when issue_text like '%error%' then 'error'
 else 'not found'
end as error_type
```

the issue_text is a string that will be formatted *mostly* the same, it'll have an error, more info, then an incident number, and that is the end of the string.

```
i.e. "Can't add address. Ref Number: 9999999"
```

the problem I'm having is the number will not always be the same amount of characters away from the error message.

I was wondering if there is a way to access the substring that causes a match from the like clause. like another case statement using a regex(which i know aren't supported well in sql)

```
case
 when issue_text like '%[0-9 .]%' then (the substring match from like '%[0-9 .]%')
 else 00000
end as issue_number
```

I am restricted to solving this issue and parsing these strings from SQL Server Management Studio or yes, I'd use .net or something to leverage.

Comment: [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) returns the index of a pattern, which would give you your starting position.

Comment: but is the error number always the last token in the string? so we could make something up with REVERSE and SUBSTRING?

Comment: @dlatikay it is always the last in the string, I will try to utilize after patindex which also looks like a viable option. will return with results

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,issue_text varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Can''t add address. Ref Number: 9999999'),
(2,'error')


Select ID
      ,Issue   = Left(issue_text,PatIndex('%:%',issue_text+':')-1)
      ,IssueNo = substring(issue_text,PatIndex('%:%',issue_text+':')+2,25)
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
ID  Issue                           IssueNo
1   Can't add address. Ref Number   9999999
2   error
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's always a space just before the number and the number is the last part of the string you can do

```
RIGHT(issue_text, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(issue_text)) - 1)
```